# different object type returned than the one in function body swift objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have been searching day and night for this. I seem to be the first one getting such an annoying error. I have a swift app and have imported an objective C framework(XlsxReaderWriter) by cocoa pods. Everything is working except Nothing is returned as the type specified in the functions in the objective C framework. Everything is returned as Any.

Forexample;

```
inputFile: BRAWorksheet = file.workbook.worksheets![0] //this gives me a compile error saying "Can not assign value of type Any to BRAWorksheet"
```

and here is the property declaration in objective C

```
- (NSArray *)worksheets {
    NSMutableArray *worksheets = @[].mutableCopy;

    for (BRASheet *sheet in _sheets) {
        BRAWorksheet *worksheet = [self.relationships relationshipWithId:sheet.identifier];
        worksheet.styles = _styles;
        worksheet.sharedStrings = _sharedStrings;
        worksheet.calcChain = _calcChain;
        [worksheets addObject:worksheet];
    }

    return worksheets.count ? worksheets : nil;
}
```

even in the documentation for the library, that is how they do it;

```
var firstWorksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0]
```

So can anyone tell me what this strange error is please?? I am getting desperate.

PS: I do not want to cast for some reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `NSArray *`, set the return type of the method to `NSArray<BRAWorksheet *> *`.

Comment: Thank you @Charles Srstka. But can you edit your question and include the updated version of `Worksheets`? I dont have enough experience in Objective C

Comment: In the body of your code, you can just do the same thing to the declaration: change `NSMutableArray *worksheets` to `NSMutableArray <BRAWorksheet *> *`. In general, you should always add the contained type in brackets after NS(Mutable)Array, if you're interacting with Swift. `NSArray <Foo *> *` will bridge to `[Foo]`, whereas just `NSArray *` will bridge to `[Any]`.